# Como puedo evitar que una alerta se sobreponga sobre otra en Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, ios, programación-móvil, bloc

Tengo un Quizapp que estoy haciendo y he implementado un funcion en la que tienes 3 vidas y si las pierdes el sistema te manda una alerta sugiriéndote repasar otra vez la lección. El problema es que cuando pierdo mis 3 vidas me lanza 3 alertas una arriba de otra llevo semanas tratando de solucionarlo. PD: todo esta dentro de un bloc supongo que tiene que ver, pero no se como solucionarle si alguien me ayuda o me da un Tip se lo agradecería muchísimo ya que no es la primera vez que me pasa, hace un tiempo tuve el mismo Problema con otra app en flutter, siempre me da problema cuando quiero mostrar alertas usando bloc.

El error empieza en el ultimo if en donde dice state.vidas == 0

----CODIGO----

```
class PartidaPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const PartidaPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final data = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String,dynamic>;
    final Niveles nivel = data['nivel'];
    final User    user  = data['user']; 

    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final partidaBloc = BlocProvider.of<PartidaBloc>(context);
    final _pageController = PageController();

    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: AppThemes.quizColor,
          appBar: AppBar(
            actions: [ 
              BlocBuilder<PartidaBloc, PartidaState>(
                builder: (context, state)  {
                  if(nivel.nombreNivel == 'DIFICIL'){

                    if(state.vidas == 0){
                      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
                        (_) async => await MyAlerts.sinVidas(context, user)
                      );
                    }
```

Comment: agrega un flag que cuando muestre la alerta, el flag se active, y mientras ese flag siga activado(el dialog aún no se ha cerrado), no puedes mostrar otra alerta

Comment: Ante todo gracias Diego, soy tu fan jajaja veo toda las noches tus videos, como así que un flag? a que te refieres? te agradecería si fueras algo mas explicito :( please!!!

Comment: En este caso, lo del Flag es mala idea, desde mi punto de vista. El problema radica en que estás usando BlocBuilder para lanzar un método, `sinVidas`. Para este tipo de lógicas, debes usar un BlocListener, que escuche un estado concreto del bloc y lance el método que desees. Debes usar BlocBuilder solo para reconstruir la pantalla, mostrar un diálogo, no es reconstruir, sino lanzar un método que hará `push` de un nuevo widget, el diálogo, en el stack de navegación.

Comment: sin en el bloc listener , le mandas 2 eventos para mostrar popups, va a mostrar los 2 de igual manera, parece que solo quiere mantener uno abierto

Comment: Dice que se le muestra 3 veces el mismo popup, según entiendo. Bloc no emite el mismo evento. Sí bloc verifica que el evento es idéntico al anterior, no actualiza el estado, por lo que el listener no se ejecutará. Aunque quizás estoy malentendiendo algo y no termino de capturar lo que está preguntando. De todos modos, para llamar a métodos que tienen que ejecutarse según el estado de la app, se debería usar el bloc_listener, creo.

Comment: Es que con el listener me pasa igual, muestra un montón de veces, supuse que si es por el bloc, pero estoy tratando de ver como ejecutarlo sin la necesidad de que este en el bloc. quería subir un gif para que comprendieran mejor, pero pesaba 10 mb

Comment: PD: si me explicarán que es un flag se los agradecería mucho, porque ni idea xD

Comment: FLAG = BANDERA. Se refiere a un bool (variable tipo true/false), que se usa para permitir que ocurra o no, alguna cosa. Por ejemplo, en tu caso, podrías hacer podrías añadir una condición extra al if para que solo se muestre cuando la vida sea igual a 0 y no se haya mostrado el popup. Cuando entres al if, podrías cambiar el valor de la variable que estás usando para verificar si se puede entrar al if y de esa forma, ya no se vuelve a entrar. Cuando el popup se quite, deberás resetear el valor de la variable para que se pueda volver a entrar al if.

Comment: De todos modos, sigo pensando que la opción del flag, no es la mejor en este caso. Seguramente, tengas algún otro tipo de problema, como no estar sobreescribiendo el equal y el hashcode o estar emitiendo el mismo estado para realizar varias acciones. Te recomendaría leerte la documentación del Flutter_Bloc y realizar algunos de los ejemplos que vienen guiado. Seguro que así, a futuro, te ahorras muchos quebraderos de cabezas ^^.